# Проблема с входом в Skype аккаунт через Skype4j

Tags: java, skype

Пишу бота для Skype проблем не было в процессе тестирования так как использовал свой аккаунт где логин  типа "User123".
Но когда зарегистрировал новый аккаунт специально для бота мне присвоили имя пользователя типа "live:1234567890zxcvbnm" и с этим проблема.
Получаю ошибку

```
While logging in (401 Unauthorized)
```

Через пошту и номер телефона тоже не получается залогинится такая же ошибка.
Как  можно решить проблему?
Пример кода:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     new SkypeBot();
    }

 public SkypeBot() {
        Skype skype = new SkypeBuilder(Config.NAME, Config.PASSWORD).withAllResources().build();

        try {
            skype.login();
        } catch (NotParticipatingException e) {
            System.out.println("Not participating.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidCredentialsException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid credentials.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        skype.getEventDispatcher().registerListener(new Chat());

        try {
            skype.subscribe();
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            skype.setVisibility(Visibility.ONLINE);
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Logging in.");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зайти в Skype через логин типа live:1234567890zxcvbnm используя Skype4j не можно.
Skype4j поддерживает логин типа User123.
Нашел как решить данную проблему тут [Github](https://github.com/EPAMHackathons/2017-mogilev-KBAK/tree/2da8978a0716711cfa21bc2d89a9febaee90776a/bot-client/src/main/java/com/epam/hackaton/bot/skype)